# Conflicting opinions on treatment of COVID-19 shortness of breath

Tags: covid-19, treatment

There are two authoritative conflicting opinions on treatment of COVID-19 shortness of breath that came from physicians in the front-lines last week. David Price, MD said there's no need to go to a hospital unless you are short of breath, in a very widely circulated Zoom talk with friends and family. Richard Levitan, MD in a NY Times editorial, said  that shortness of breath can come days after pneumonia starts and serious damage has already begun, and everyone complaining of COVID-19 symptoms should be tested  for oxygen saturation immediately and hospitalized if it's low.  Has there been any follow-on? I'd expect one or the other or both to say something and a lot of other opinions would be offered. David Price is a pulmonolgist and that, all by itself, says a lot. Richard Levitan tells what he's actually seen, and is quite convincing. He also points out that pulse oximeters are widely available and inexpensive.

Links:
https://www.nytimes.com/2020/04/20/opinion/coronavirus-testing-pneumonia.html
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kcKTzefEJFM

Comment: You need to provide links

Comment: No one is going to watch a one hour video.

Comment: What, exactly, is the question?

Comment: @Carey Gregory the implicit question was "Who's right?" and if it's not settled - somehow - the stated question was "Has there been any follow-on?"

Comment: @Graham Chiu The stay-home-unless-you're-short-of-breath segment starts at about minute 25. Dr. Price's enunciation is good enough for double speed playback, so the entire video can be played in 28 minutes. There's also a condensed version available online.